# Div placement problems

Tags: css, html

I have this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqCGd/.

It contains a large `messages` div that contains `message` divs. These `message` divs are automatically generated, but for the sake of this example and simplicity I left out the auto-generation of such divs and provided one example of a message div.

Inside the `message` div there are 4 div children:

1. `dir` which contains an image: I am currently using a test image for this
2. `a` which contains 3 sets of data, the top `p` tag contains a rather long string, so it is smaller than the rest of the other `p` tags
3. `b` which contains yet another 3 sets of data, where this time the last `p` tag is rather lengthy and requires a smaller font size
4. `c` which just contains a button called `view`

**Problem**:
If you look at `a`, `b` or `c`, you might notice that the divs seem to "fall" for lack of other words. The y-position of the div seems to be off for each element with the exception of the `dir` div. They are meant to be side-by-side with the same y-position. If you are having problems seeing this affect, you can use Google Chromes "inspect element" tool and find where these tags are. Hovering over them in the element inspector should show a blue box that displays the encapsulation size and position of the div. You should see that `a` is lower than `dir`, `b` is lower than `a`, `c` is lower than `b`. The `button` should also appear in between the div boundary (partially shown).

**What I want:**
I need to get the divs: `a`, `b` and `c`'s y-position to be the same as `dir`'s y-position. Preferably with CSS.

*Please note:* Google Chrome is my test target. So do not worry about IE or any other browser for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example with `{vertical-align: top}` applied to .a, .b, and .c. Maybe that's what you're after.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pqCGd/1/

Comment: Great, that fixed it! But what caused the problem in the first place?

Comment: @jakebird451 By default, inline* elements are vertically aligned on the baseline:  http://jsfiddle.net/fW7jv/

Comment: @jakebird451 be sure they are always display:inline-block; because if they are not inline-block or table-cell then vertical-align will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understand it right. You can add `float: left;` to `div.message div` . so they will sit side by side to each other.

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqCGd/2/)

Comment: This should work, too. I tend to avoid using floats unless I actually want content to flow around them. They have their own set of challenges.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to change it after the page is loaded you can change it in jQuery using this code

```
var offset = $(".dir").offset();
$(".a").offset({ top: offset.top});
$(".b").offset({ top: offset.top});
$(".c").offset({ top: offset.top});
```

Here is the result
http://jsfiddle.net/ekvU9/1/

Note that .offset() get the positions related to the document so you are quite sure that the offset will be right in all browsers.